# Help required regarding punctuation in a sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am trying to write the following sentence:

*We see then, that the purpose of life is simply the program of the pleasure principle.*

I am, however, not sure about how I would correctly punctuate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, the first one being rather rare.

- We see, then, that…
- We see then that…

There are  examples of both practices [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we%20see%20then%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).